# Mass Effect 2 - Fight for the Lost.. Actors?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I had access to a Mass Effect 2 DVD which has among other things a short-medium video with presenting the main characters of game name **Fight for the Lost**.

I was watching it, even without subtitles, and when Thane appeared I noticed him VERY different than he is in game. Not perfect as a true CG of course, more like part CG, part human cosplay.

A few minutes later appeared an actress looking very similar to Jack. The haircut, the makeup, the "charming" way of speak with all the sex appeal of her lips movements...

I tried to search more about them but I can only find rips of these scenes on Youtube, but no name, not other detail. So, are they real persons? Is there a full cast somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were watching the "Fight for the Lost" crew interviews on the collector's edition dvd.

Here's [Miranda](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhIFCyGGI1w) and here's [Jack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eNqzoKG6X0).

As you can see at the start and end, this is just renders using models and textures not found in the game.  There's no human actress present.

Comment: Really? If Jack looked like that in game I would bring her to fight more often (I pick her only for Haestrom mission and The Long Walk in Collector's Base). But I guess you right. Even very realist, it's perfectly clear that Miranda is not Yvonne Strahovski, for example. Thank you